# Python variables lose scope inside generator?

Tags: python, scope, generator

The code below returns `NameError: global name 'self' is not defined`. Why?

```
lengths = [3, 10]
self.fooDict = getOrderedDict(stuff)

if not all(0 < l < len(self.fooDict) for l in lengths):
    raise ValueError("Bad lengths!")
```

Note that `self.fooDict` is an OrderedDict (imported from the collections library) that has 35 entries. When I try to debug, the code below executes without error:

```
(Pdb) len(self.dataDict)
35
(Pdb) all(0 < size < 35 for size in lengths)
True
```

But the debugginf code below gives me the original error:

```
(Pdb) baz = len(self.dataDict)
(Pdb) all(0 < size < baz for size in lengths)
NameError: global name 'baz' is not defined
```

Comment: posting a little more code might help you better

Comment: Need more context. Does the method that contains this code define a `self` parameter?

Comment: `pdb` doesn't give the generator access to the locals, no. That's a limit of how `pdb` evaluates the code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Short answer and workaround

You've run into a limitation of the debugger. Expressions entered into the debugger cannot use *non-locally scoped values* because the debugger cannot create the required closures.

You could instead create a *function* to run your generator, thus creating a new scope at the same time:

```
def _test(baz, lengths):
    return all(0 < size < baz for size in lengths)

_test(len(self.dataDict), lengths)
```

Note that this applies to set and dictionary comprehensions as well, and in Python 3, list comprehensions.

### The long answer, why this happens

Generator expressions (and set, dict and Python 3 list comprehensions) run in a new, nested namespace. The name `baz` in your generator expression is not a local in that namespace, so Python has to find it somewhere else. *At compile time* Python determines where to source that name from. It'll search from the scopes the *compiler* has available and if there are no matches, declares the name a global.

Here are two generator expressions to illustrate:

```
def function(some_iterable):
    gen1 = (var == spam for var in some_iterable)

    ham = 'bar'
    gen2 = (var == ham for var in some_iterable)

    return gen1, gen2
```

The name `spam` is not found in the parent scope, so the compiler marks it as a global:

```
>>> dis.dis(function.__code__.co_consts[1])  # gen1
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    3 FOR_ITER                17 (to 23)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (var)
              9 LOAD_FAST                1 (var)
             12 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (spam)
             15 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             18 YIELD_VALUE         
             19 POP_TOP             
             20 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
        >>   23 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             26 RETURN_VALUE
```

The opcode at index 12 uses `LOAD_GLOBAL` to load the `spam` name.

The name `ham` *is* found in the function scope, so the compiler generates bytecode to look up the name as a closure from the function. *At the same time* the name `ham` is marked as a closure; the variable is treated differently by the code generated for `function` so that you can still reference it when the function has returned.

```
>>> dis.dis(function.__code__.co_consts[3])  # gen2
  4           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    3 FOR_ITER                17 (to 23)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (var)
              9 LOAD_FAST                1 (var)
             12 LOAD_DEREF               0 (ham)
             15 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             18 YIELD_VALUE         
             19 POP_TOP             
             20 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            3
        >>   23 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             26 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> function.__code__.co_cellvars  # closure cells
('ham',)
```

The name `ham` is loaded with a `LOAD_DEREF` opcode, and the function code object has listed that name as a closure. When you disassemble `function` you'll find, among other bytecode:

```
>>> dis.dis(function)
  # ....

  4          22 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (ham)
             25 BUILD_TUPLE              1
             28 LOAD_CONST               3 (<code object <genexpr> at 0x1074a87b0, file "<stdin>", line 4>)
             31 MAKE_CLOSURE             0
             34 LOAD_FAST                0 (some_iterable)
             37 GET_ITER            
             38 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             41 STORE_FAST               2 (gen2)

  # ...
```

where the `LOAD_CLOSURE` and `MAKE_CLOSURE` bytecodes create a closure for `ham` to be used by the generator code object.

When you run arbitrary expressions in the debugger, the compiler has no access to the namespace you are debugging. More importantly, it cannot *alter* that namespace to create a closure. Thus, you cannot use anything but *globals* in your generator expressions.